# phpMyAdmin error while installing

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can not access phpMyAdmin

Through my website. When I open https://my-ip-is.com/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin

Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Did you set it up right?

Comment: I don't know but now its working I just restart apache server